# How did 無 originate from "a dancer holding something in each hand"?

Tags: etymology

If someone, dancer or not, is holding something in each hand, how can [無](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%84%A1#Chinese) possibly describe him? His hands are not 無! I also screenshot [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E7%84%A1).

[image]

[image]

Comment: As it says on wiktionary, “The character is borrowed”. Could you specify what else you are looking for?

Comment: @dROOOze Even if it's borrowed, how does that pictogram explain 無? My reason remains true.

Comment: Do you mean, how does 無 *look like* a dancing person holding things in their hands? Because that’s a glyph-origin question. “Borrowed” otherwise literally means that a word doesn’t have any meaning relation with what the character originally meant.

Comment: @dROOOze No. I don't think I'm asking how "無 look like a dancing person holding things in their hands". Why's 無 represented by someone holding things in his hands? If you hold things in your hands, you possess something! 無 has no place for you.

Comment: @dROOOze Your answer below still deserves to stay though! I can post a new question if you desire.

Comment: "Rebus principle" points to a character being borrowed for its sound, not its meaning. It doesn't matter if the word that it's borrowed for seems to be contradictory to the original picture. If you're not satisfied with the idea of rebus borrowings, I'm afraid that this question can't be answered objectively.

Answer (score 4):

There might be some confusion as to what the word "borrowed" means. The usage of 「無」 to mean *without* is a rebus borrowing. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus#Rebus_principle):

> An example that illustrates the Rebus principle is the representation of the sentence "I can see you" by using the pictographs of "eye—can—sea—ewe".

That is, to ask how the sentence

> *I can see you*

originated from the pictures

> [image: Photo of an eye] [image: Photo of a can] [image: Photo of the sea] [image: Photo of an ewe and her lambs]

is an incorrect question.

---

If it is difficult to see how the glyph evolved into its current form 「無」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*ma/**, *without*), that is a more tangible query.

Start from a rather vivid picture of a person 「大」 holding a bunch of adornments in each hand, doing a **rain dance***.

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[鐵](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)120.3
[合集16000](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=16000&jgwfl=)</kbd>

Complexify the adornments, maybe into something highly resembling a sound hint [「某」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1282) (**/*məʔ/**).

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
毛伯簋
[集成4009](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=4009&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
金
[image]
寬兒鼎
[集成2722](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=2722&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
10.8
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd>
<kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
[image]</kbd>

Omit the shape of the person 「大」.

<kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image]
[老子](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao_Te_Ching)・甲
[馬王堆帛書](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawangdui_Silk_Texts)</kbd>
<kbd>隸定
[image]</kbd>

Then finally, abbreviate the bottom of the character into a few dots.

<kbd>西漢
隸
[image: 無]
25
定縣竹簡</kbd>
<kbd>[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image: 無]</kbd>

*Dance* is written with the derivative character 「舞」, by adding semantic 「舛」 (*picture of two feet*).

<kbd>西周
金
[image: 舞]
匽侯銅泡
[集成11860](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=11860&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西漢
隸
[image: 舞]
158
縱橫家書</kbd><kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
隸
[image: 舞]
華山廟碑</kbd>
　
<kbd>楷
[image: 舞]</kbd>

---

*The nature of the dance being linked with *rain* is from [the extensive number of fragments where the character 「無」 is found with the character 「雨」](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=%E8%88%9E&jgwfl=). E.g. [《甲骨文合集》12828](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=12828&jgwfl=):

[image]

> 戊（申）卜今日（奏）（舞）㞢（有）从雨
>
> [Divination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone#Shang_divination) (卜) on the day of [wùshēn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%88%8A%E7%94%B3) (戊申): Today (今日), perform (奏) a dance ritual (舞). Rain appears (有从雨).

---

**References:**

- [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/)

Comment: i would further interpret “㞢从雨” as “there’s (有) showers (驟雨)”, then people danced (舞) for celebration / appreciation the divine.

Comment: 無 doesn't encode explicit anything related to water/rain. The 灬 is actually 林. In Han Dynasty, the two short horizontal stroke merges into one and is incorporated into the upper part. The remaining part looks like 小小, first written as 6 strokes and then simplified into 4..

Comment: @lilysirius 無 doesn't have water or rain in the character, but it appears overwhelmingly with 雨. [See the oracle bone fragments where 無 appears with 雨](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=%E8%88%9E&jgwfl=). `The 灬 is actually 林` no, if you trace the glyph evolution from oracle bone glyphs, 灬 is a remnant of the bottom part of the person holding the adornments - 林 is a graphical corruption introduced around the Han dynasty.

Comment: I agree. I only meant that 林 is where 灬 directly came from, not that it's the original form. The thing that hold on hand has indeed involved into 上口下木. And the 林 form actually appeared in the Warring States Period 楚簡.

Answer (score 1):

[How did '無' originate from “a dancer holding something in each hand” (etymology, Chinese)? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-did-%E7%84%A1-originate-from-a-dancer-holding-something-in-each-hand-etymology-Chinese)

> 無 is the original character of 舞 (Old Chinese: *maʔ ), which most learners nowadays do recognize as the character that means “dance”. The driving force of the shift of its functionality is mostly phonetic and hardly semantic at all.
>
> (Worth noting that the change in written symbols should not be mistaken as etymologically development of the underlying words. People may write “i 8 pizza” for “I ate pizza” but that doesn’t mean that you can derive the sense “eating” from the number VIII. All the arrows in the following graph represent orthographical development but not necessarily etymological ones)
>
> [image]
>
> Stage 1: Although the word that means “none” probably did exist in Old Chinese[1], 無 was not originally intended for writing that word. Instead, the main purpose 無 was to denote the Old Chinese word *maʔ [2] which means dance.
>
> Stage 2: At certain point, 無 started to take on another role - to denote the Old Chinese word *ma that means “none” [3]. The process of a character is re-purposed to denote another word that is phonetically (as opposed semantically) similar to its original word is called “通假”. It happened quite often in the writing system of Old Chinese. Through 通假, the character 無 started to be shared by two phonetically similar yet semantically unrelated words: *maʔ “dance” and *ma “none”.
>
> Stage 3: either for the concern of clarity or for some other reasons, the situation that one character denotes both “dance” and “none” did not last too long. People started to write them differently by adding something extra when they mean *maʔ “dance” - whence the character 舞. Now, having been relieved of the duty to denote *maʔ “dance”, 無 became exclusively reserved for the word *ma “none”.
>
> [1] One of the archaic variants for writing the word *ma “none” was actually 无, which the Simplified character is based on.
>
> [2] *maʔ “dance” has gradually changed its pronunciation over the past thousands of years. That’s the word wu3 “dance” that you see in dictionaries.
>
> [3] likewise, *ma “none” changed its pronunciation over the years too. Its canonical descendant is the word wu2 “none” that you see in dictionaries .

Comment: Thanks for so ably answering your own question. Much appreciated.